# Data receiving in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, spark-streaming

Recently I've been doing performance tests on Spark Streaming. But some problems puzzled me a lot.
In Spark Streaming, receivers are scheduled to run in executors on worker nodes.

1. How many receivers are there in a cluster? Can I control the number of receivers?
2. If not all workers run receiver to receive stream data, the other worker nodes will not receive any data? In that case, how can I guarantee task scheduling based on data locality? Copy data from nodes those run receivers?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one receiver per `DStream`, but you can create more than one `DStream` and `union` them together to act as one. This is why it is suggested to run `Spark Streaming` against a cluster that is at least `N`(receivers) + 1 cores. Once the data is past the receiving portion, it is mostly a simple `Spark` application and follows the same rules of a batch job. (This is why streaming is referred to as micro-batching)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there is no receiver running on a worker node, is it possible be scheduled to run tasks(there is no data on it?)? In that case, how can I guarantee data-locality scheduling?